# Unable to read module manifest error after successful compile of Unreal Engine

Tags: c++, visual-studio, manifest, unreal-engine5

Using VS 2022 Community Edition successfully compile the Nvidia NVRTX 5.1 Caustics branch.
However on attempting to launch any of the sample projects I get a crash with the following error message
"Unable to read module manifest from....
https://imgur.com/a/9qltTMT

In checking my build files I see that there has been no UnrealEditor.modules file generated.